# Program to find greatest common divisor

Tags: c++, greatest-common-divisor

Here's a c++ program i tried to write for the above question.Our teacher told us to use a for loop.

```
void main()

int A[30],B[30],m,n,i,j,x,z;

cout<< "enter two numbers";
cin>>m>>n;
for(i=1,j=0;i<=m,j<30;i++,j++)
{
  if(m%i==0)
   { A[j]=i;
     z=j;
   }
}
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<30;i++,j++)
{ 
  if(n%i==0)
  { B[j]=i;
    x=j;
  }
}

for(i=z;i>=0;--i)
{
  for(j=x;j>=0;--j)
    {
    if(A[i]==B[j])
      { cout<<"gcd="<<A[i];
      }
    }
}
}
```

The output displays " Enter two numbers:" and when i entered 15 and 3, the result i got was a blinking cursor. Working through the program, I realised that the divisors for each number when stored in the arrays of A and B were not stored continuously or had gaps in between. If there isn't anything in the memory for say A[11], what happens when you check it against another variable with a number? Can somebody please modify this to make it work and tell me what's wrong? I am new to programming, so excuse my program if it is clumsy.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong amongst a number of other things like out of bounds indexing. Please learn how to use the debugger to inspect your code.

Comment: `i<=m,j<30` doesn't do what you think... you probably wanted `&&` instead of `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas has pointed out that there are other ways to achieve the goal of finding the gcd, but the point of the exercise is to get a better handle on some basic programming constructs. So lets go with your approach.

Your idea is to compute the two lists of divisors and then compare them. As you say, having a list with gaps in makes this harder.

So adapt your loop, only increment the storage index when you've stored something

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=m && j<30;i++) // need the && here; a comma means something different
{
  if(m%i==0)
   { A[j++]=i;
     z=j;
   }
}
```

Second, you have a typo you're not storing in B, so fix that

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n && j<30;i++)
{ 
  if(n%i==0)
  { B[j++]=i; //B here not A
    x=j;
  }
}
```

That should help.

Comment: I understand and have implemented the change in the increment. I tried compiling again and this time I got the output "divide error" . I don't even know what that means. Please do help. I am unable to understand the &&. It's multiple initialization and I can't put && there. How exactly should i use  &&?

Comment: In the for loop's conditional; you want to say "keep going as long as both these things are true"  both is an AND, use && to say that.

Comment: As for the "divide error" that's usually when you try to do an impossible division, like dividing by zero. I can't see how that could happen in the code you posted. Do you know how to step through your code in a debugger? Really worth learning to do that, then you can see exactly where it goes wrong and the values of the variables at the time. Otherwise add some print statements to understand what it happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

As taken from here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66711/greatest-common-divisor